# Weird AWS S3 Links

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm wondering why my endpoint works but the other URL doesn't work?

endpoint: http://data-flood.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

other URL: http://data-flood.s3.amazonaws.com/

I get access denied.

Answer (score 0):

This is because an S3 bucket that has been configured for website hosting is region-specific.

[Via the docs:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html)

> When you configure a bucket for website hosting, the website is available via the region-specific website endpoint.

[See a list of valid S3 endpoints here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_website_region_endpoints)

Comment: Do you want to set up a custom/friendly domain for your S3 site? If so, these instructions will be helpful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Comment: @RichardTrinh can you pass region in query param?.`http://data-flood.s3.amazonaws.com?region=us-east-1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the pages explicitly if you use the bucket.s3.amazonaws.com endpoint instead bucket.s3-website-.amazonaws.com endpoint, For your cases your page will be visible in http://data-flood.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html, Basically, Website hosting capability can be accessed only through bucket.s3-website-.amazonaws.com endpoint, if you are access direct endpoint, you need to give the paths explicitly.